# How to auto-run a php script when certain condition is true?

Tags: php, scripting, autorun

for example something like

```
if(new_user_registered() == true):
   send_success_mail();
endif;
```

I want to execute the script **independent** from **user-end** since **too much stuff happening** on user registration is slowing down the forum submitting process resulting in inappropriate and missing data.

Due to client privacy cannot reveal too much about the project. And I am a relatively new in programming so my explanation might not be that clear sorry for that in advance.

Comment: You could set up a [cron job](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) that checks periodically (e.g. every 5 minutes) for newly registered users and sends out the success mails.

Comment: that's the idea for now but I hoped to find conditional trigging so it runs every time  on successful new registration but directly on server independent from user end { mostly issue here is users internet connection or in case where suddenly internet got cut off in mid  }